# require.ensure not working after moving webpack from root directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I used to have a folder structure like this:

```
[development]
--[app]
----[dist]
------[js]
--------app.js
--------contact-support.0.js
----[src]
--[node_modules]
--package.json  
--webpack.config.js
--index.php
[tools]
```

but moved everything related to webpack from root directory to `tools/webpack`:

```
[development]
--[app]
----[dist]
------[js]
--------app.js
--------contact-support.0.js
----[src]
--index.php
[tools]
--[webpack]
----[node_modules]
----package.json  
----webpack.config.js
```

So I run webpack now from `tools/webpack` and most of paths in `webpack.config.js` are preceeded by `./../../development`.

And everything works, apart from those dang chunks (created by `require.ensure()`).

I have no errors on webpack compile and no errors in Chrome's console, but when I stumble on part of code that dynamically loads a chunk I get:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
```

I know it doesn't tell much, but from my experience for 99% it has to be related to webpack's path handling.

The devil is hidden here:

```
output:  {
  chunkFilename: './../../development' + '/app/dist/js/[name].[id].js',
  publicPath:    'http://localhost/YDR/branches/refactoring/tools/webpack/'
},
```

The problem is that when webpack generates the chunk file it is done in different directory (`./tools/webpack/`) than when app tries to load it (`./development/`), so I cannot use relative paths and need be little hacky here.

Theoretically these paths are correct:

- **on save**: the path in which the chunk file is saved is the path from where I'm running webpack (`tools/webpack` which is same as publicPath), but elevated 2 levels up to `http://localhost/YDR/branches/refactoring/development/app/dist/js/`
- **on load**: the path from which I load the chunk file is generated from publicPath + chunkFilename which also resolves to `http://localhost/YDR/branches/refactoring/development/app/dist/js/`

However, it still breaks when I reach:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('body').on('click', '[data-target="#contactSupport"]', function () {
            require.ensure([
                './../modules/contact-support/contact-support.js' // files that chunk will contain
            ], (require) => {
                require('./../modules/contact-support/contact-support.js'); // BREAKS HERE
            }, 'contact-support'); // name of chunk file
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: FYI webpack 2's latest RC does not use `require.ensure` but `System.import` instead

Comment: Switched to System.export/import and it worked! But I also had to change publicPath from `tools/webpack` to my app's root dir.